# AIX | sed -i option not working for the specific line number

Tags: shell, aix

I want to insert/delete a line on the specific line number in aix os using script.

i was trying below code

```
no2=103
dis=<disabled></disabled>
sed "${no2} a $dis" $node > vi.xml
```

Till now, i have tried awk, executable vi command. Nothing worked yet

Error output is as follows:

```
server:/u/vwadhwa/MIMOnOffHold $ ./script.sh INTACTIX_TO_NDW_ITX007 stop
Performing stop action on dirmon-INTACTIX_TO_NDW_ITX007 which is present in node-IKBNODE01.xml
sed: Not a recognized flag: i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
```

Comment: `-i` isn't a posix option and apparently isn't implemented by aix's sed.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of in-place editing of a file by inserting text at a specific line is a good use case for `ed` of all things (Which I assume AIX has).

To insert a new line before line `$no2` (Making it the new line `$no2`; use `a` to insert after that line):

```
ed -s "$node" <<EOF
$no2 i
$dis
.
w
q
EOF
```

and to delete line `$no2`:

```
ed -s "$node" <<EOF
$no2 d
w
q
EOF
```

---

Though it appears you're working with XML, which means a tool that understands XML is going to be a better choice - what if your file changes so that blindly adding a tag at line 103 causes it to be invalid?

Comment: what is the "$node" here ?

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani What's `$node`? Presumably it's a file name; that's how you use it in your question, at least.

Comment: See what i tried, let me know if i am doing it wrong.
`laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ node=vini.txt
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ ed -s "$node" <<EOF
> 2 i
> VINITAAAAA
> w
> q
> EOF
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ cat vini.txt
vini
vinita
vinitaaa
vani`

Comment: @VinitaWadhwani That is an unreadable mess. Comments are not the place for what appears to be a multi line copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but if you just want to insert a new line, you can use something like this, where `$dis` is the line you want to insert:

```
perl -pe "s/^/$dis\n/ if \$. == $line_number" input_file > output_file
```

You can also use the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i -pe "s/^/$dis\n/ if \$. == $line_number" input_file
```

Comment: Did not work at all
```
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ dis=cini
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ line_number=5
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $  perl -i -pe "s/^/$dis\n/ if \$. == $line_number" vini.txt
laq9esbpt225:/u/qmima20/MIMOnOffHold $ cat vini.txt
vini
vinita
vinitaaa
vani
```

Comment: There are only 4 lines in your file, but you've specified the 5th line?

Comment: In what way? You can add it to a shell script the same as you can any other command